# PostgreSQL - Why is it choosing the wrong plan ? CLUSTER index makes BRIN index invisible even if it's cheaper

Tags: postgresql, optimization

Summary : 2 tables contain identical data. I want to see the impact of re-ordering the tuples into an order which, should help. I want to show someone how adding a BRIN index helps here.
Why does the presence of a BTREE index (which is not used) appear to make the BRIN index invisible ?

Table cf1 is CLUSTERED on an index on (bizdate,datepayment)
Table cf2 is simply create table cf2 as select  * from cf1 ORDER BY bizdate,datepayment;

Both tables have same size (14GB).

Version : PostgreSQL 14.2

```
mydb=# \d+ cf1
                                                Unlogged table "public.cf1"
     Column       |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
------------------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 pa               | text             |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 bizdate          | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 en               | text             |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 as               | text             |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 bo               | integer          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 con              | text             |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 cur              | character(3)     |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 cuv              | integer          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 cuid             | integer          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 datepayment      | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 dateb            | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 datee            | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 disc             | integer          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 discdate         | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 df               | double precision |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 deleted          | boolean          |           |          | false   | plain    |             |              |
Indexes:
    "bizdate_brin" brin (bizdate)
    "cf1_clust" btree (bizdate, datepayment) CLUSTER    
Access method: heap


mydb=# \d+ cf2
                                                Unlogged table "public.cf2"
     Column       |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description
------------------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 pa               | text             |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 bizdate          | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 en               | text             |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 as               | text             |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 bo               | integer          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 con              | text             |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 cur              | character(3)     |           |          |         | extended |             |              |
 cuv              | integer          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 cuid             | integer          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 datepayment      | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 dateb            | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 datee            | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 disc             | integer          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 discdate         | date             |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 df               | double precision |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 deleted          | boolean          |           |          |         | plain    |             |              |
 
 ndexes:
    "bizdate_brin2" brin (bizdate)
Access method: heap
```

Both tables are analyzed. pg_stats is checked and shows, as expected, that I have achieved my desired correlation on those columns.

```
select tablename,attname,correlation from pg_stats where tablename in ('cf1','cf2') and attname in ('bizdate','datepayment');
 tablename |   attname   | correlation
-----------+-------------+-------------
 cf1       | bizdate     |           1
 cf1       | datepayment |  0.26412892
 cf2       | bizdate     |           1
 cf2       | datepayment |  0.25495368
(4 rows)
```

Both tables have the same BRIN index created.
Each table has 100 million rows and I explain analyze.

I am struggling to explain why the planner chooses a sub-optimal plan for the CLUSTERED table.

The choice to use the BRIN index seems cheaper. And indeed, when I drop the index I used for hte CLUSTERing, the planner does indeed revert back to using the BRIN index. So, even though the BTREE index is not used, the mere presence of it appears to make the optimizer choose a sub-optimal plan.

Here I will copy the plans from the SAME query on each table. Can anyone explain why it chose the plan for table cf1 when the plan used on cf2 is cheaper?

Specifically, the cost of the Parallel Seq Scan on table cf1 is
Parallel Seq Scan on public.cf1  (cost=0.00..2255682.04 rows=14612 width=0) (actual time=11818.957..30399.976 rows=22887 loops=5)

compared to the choice of a BRIN index for the table cf2 query.
The BRIN index is available on both tables. Why not use it?

```
mydb=# explain (verbose,analyze,buffers,settings)
select count(*) from cf1 where bizdate>='2022-12-03' and datepayment<='2022-12-20' and bo=158;
                                                                                                    QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2256718.98..2256718.99 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=30432.574..30435.998 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   Buffers: shared hit=178 read=1818004
   ->  Gather  (cost=2256718.56..2256718.97 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=30432.243..30435.991 rows=5 loops=1)
         Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
         Workers Planned: 4
         Workers Launched: 4
         Buffers: shared hit=178 read=1818004
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2255718.56..2255718.57 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=30404.713..30404.714 rows=1 loops=5)
               Output: PARTIAL count(*)
               Buffers: shared hit=178 read=1818004
               Worker 0:  actual time=30397.894..30397.894 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=26 read=347556
               Worker 1:  actual time=30398.147..30398.147 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=26 read=360831
               Worker 2:  actual time=30397.909..30397.909 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=17 read=371470
               Worker 3:  actual time=30398.042..30398.042 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=23 read=371571
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.cf1  (cost=0.00..2255682.04 rows=14612 width=0) (actual time=11818.957..30399.976 rows=22887 loops=5)
                     Output: pa, bizdate, en, as, bo, con, cuid, datepayment, dateb datee, disc, discdate, df, deleted
                     Filter: ((cf1.bizdate >= '2022-12-03'::date) AND (cf1.datepayment <= '2022-12-20'::date) AND (cf1.bo = 158))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 19977113
                     Buffers: shared hit=178 read=1818004
                     Worker 0:  actual time=11852.733..30393.191 rows=21513 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=26 read=347556
                     Worker 1:  actual time=11833.731..30393.100 rows=27020 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=26 read=360831
                     Worker 2:  actual time=11773.836..30393.242 rows=21818 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=17 read=371470
                     Worker 3:  actual time=11810.401..30393.361 rows=21625 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared hit=23 read=371571
 Settings: jit = 'off', max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '4', random_page_cost = '1.05', work_mem = '1284MB'
 Query Identifier: -4390557446573982976
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=27 read=1
 Planning Time: 4.355 ms
 Execution Time: 30436.083 ms
(38 rows)

-------- AND NOW THE SAME QUERY BUT ON CF2

db=# explain (verbose,analyze,buffers,settings)
select count(*) from cf2 where bizdate>='2022-12-03' and datepayment<='2022-12-20' and bo=158;
                                                                         QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2038645.18..2038645.19 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=23653.900..23690.750 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   Buffers: shared hit=14 read=909171 written=2
   ->  Gather  (cost=2038644.76..2038645.17 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=23653.540..23690.742 rows=5 loops=1)
         Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
         Workers Planned: 4
         Workers Launched: 4
         Buffers: shared hit=14 read=909171 written=2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2037644.76..2037644.77 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=23628.730..23628.731 rows=1 loops=5)
               Output: PARTIAL count(*)
               Buffers: shared hit=14 read=909171 written=2
               Worker 0:  actual time=23622.990..23622.991 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared read=181905
               Worker 1:  actual time=23622.823..23622.824 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared read=182060
               Worker 2:  actual time=23622.747..23622.749 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared read=181390
               Worker 3:  actual time=23622.751..23622.752 rows=1 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared read=181871 written=1
               ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on public.cf2  (cost=291.18..2037608.14 rows=14645 width=0) (actual time=24.447..23624.389 rows=22887 loops=5)
                     Recheck Cond: (cf2.bizdate >= '2022-12-03'::date)
                     Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 384
                     Filter: ((cf2.datepayment <= '2022-12-20'::date) AND (cf2.bo = 158))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 9977113
                     Heap Blocks: lossy=181900
                     Buffers: shared hit=14 read=909171 written=2
                     Worker 0:  actual time=18.524..23618.735 rows=22767 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared read=181905
                     Worker 1:  actual time=18.412..23618.548 rows=22761 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared read=182060
                     Worker 2:  actual time=18.696..23618.346 rows=23152 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared read=181390
                     Worker 3:  actual time=18.590..23618.323 rows=22820 loops=1
                       Buffers: shared read=181871 written=1
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bizdate_brin2  (cost=0.00..276.53 rows=50087993 width=0) (actual time=45.172..45.172 rows=9091260 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (cf2.bizdate >= '2022-12-03'::date)
                           Buffers: shared hit=14 read=45
 Settings: jit = 'off', max_parallel_workers_per_gather = '4', random_page_cost = '1.05', work_mem = '1284MB'
 Query Identifier: -6919457055154099358
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning Time: 0.680 ms
 Execution Time: 23692.325 ms
(43 rows)
```

I dropped the cluster index on cf1 and it then used the cheaper_faster plan of using the BRIN index, same as cf2's plan above.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! did you know we have [DBA's Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)? they sure will be interested with this kind of thing.